# QGC crashes every time when the AVD runs

Tags: c++, qt, android-emulator, mavlink, px4

I am trying to build the android version of QGC using Qt creator via an emulator.

The AVD that I have created runs with the QGC app installed successfully in it.

The app opens for 1 minute and then keeps on crashing.

Build details:

- QT 5.15.2
- ABI armeabi-v7a
- AVD and its respective emulator:

  [image: AVD]
- JDK and SDK file configurations:

  [image: JDK and SDK]
- Packages and images installed for the AVD:

  [image: Images]

I have followed each detail from this manual of [QGC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html#android-sdk).

This is the error I receive once the emulator is closed:

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\Bismah\androidSdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\armeabi-v7a
WARNING | encryption is off
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Bismah\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.43.1
INFO | added library vulkan-1.dll
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO | Advertising in: C:\Users\Bismah\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_228.ini
INFO | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 720x1280, dpi: 320x320
ERROR | ColorBuffer::create get gl error 0x502 before creating textures
glTexImage2D: got err pre :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
glTexImage2D: got err :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
ERROR | Create color buffer failed.
ERROR | ColorBuffer::create get gl error 0x502 before creating textures
glTexImage2D: got err pre :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
glTexImage2D: got err :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
ERROR | Create color buffer failed.
ERROR | ColorBuffer::create get gl error 0x502 before creating textures
glTexImage2D: got err pre :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
glTexImage2D: got err :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
ERROR | Create color buffer failed.
ERROR | ColorBuffer::create get gl error 0x502 before creating textures
glTexImage2D: got err pre :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
glTexImage2D: got err :frowning: 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
ERROR | Create color buffer failed.
```